# How can I sort an arraylist based on the name and the Arraylist contains name with Initial of a person?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections, comparable

For Example: 
I have `[A John, B Adam, K Henry]` added in an `ArrayList`.

I want the output as `[B Adam, K Henry, A John]`

Sorted based on the name, But when sorting it should not consider the initial of a person. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Try writing a comparator.

Comment: what about using fields like: ***surname*** and ***forename***

Comment: @uoyilmaz can't we achieve this using comparable?

Comment: @Syed, we can, but comparable has unly one single way of comparing itself to other. There's no point in using comparable unless there is a specific way to compare entities that makes most sense in their problem domain. In case of entities such as "people", there's way more than one way of comparison, so comparator is more suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest to use a better object then String in your list.
In that case you can use a Comparator for sorting out your list, or make your object Comparable.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ComparatorExample {

    static class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
        private String initial;
        private String surName;

        public Person(final String initial, final String surName) {
            this.initial = initial;
            this.surName = surName;
        }

        public String getInitial() {
            return initial;
        }

        public void setInitial(final String initial) {
            this.initial = initial;
        }

        public String getSurName() {
            return surName;
        }

        public void setSurName(final String surName) {
            this.surName = surName;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(final Person o) {
            return surName.compareTo(o.surName);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return initial + ' ' + surName;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person a = new Person("A", "John");
        Person b = new Person("B", "Adam");
        Person c = new Person("K", "Henry");
        ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(a);
        list.add(b);
        list.add(c);

        System.out.println(list);

        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares only the names:

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A John", "B Adam", "K Henry");
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.split(" ")[1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use compareTo() method.. first split the names using space split(" ") then save all names in string array use compareTo() for prev word and curr word..

Answer (score 1):

Create a class `Person` for your persons and use a `Comparator` to sort the list.

---

**Class for person:**

```
public class Person {

    private String surname;
    private String forename;

    public Person(String forename, String surname) {
      this.surname = surname;
      this.forename = forename;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
      return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
      this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getForename() {
      return forename;
    }

    public void setForename(String forename) {
      this.forename = forename;
    }
  }
```

**Sorting:**

```
  @Test
  public void testSortPersons() {
    List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(new Person("John", "A"),
                                        new Person("Adam", "B"),
                                        new Person("Henry", "K"));
    people.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getForename));
  }
```

---

It would be generally a more robust approach to have a class containing the data of your persons instead of using `Strings`.